# Can't read old file.xls excel file with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

My code works perfect with `file.xlsx` but I can't make it work with old `file.xls`. I tried every code I found and nothing works... I tried change the version of `Excel2007`to 2003,2004 but nothing... Don't know what else to try.
Here is my current code (working with `file.xlsx` but I need to work with `file.xls` too).

```
 <?php 
 function load_table(){
    require_once('Classes/PHPExcel.php');

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(false);

    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("SampleData.xlsx");
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'

    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5

    echo '<table class="table">' . "\n";
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
      echo '<tr>' . "\n";

      for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
        echo '<td>';
        $first =   $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
        if($first[0] == '='){

            echo $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getCalculatedValue();
        }
        else
            echo $first;

        echo '</td>' . "\n";

      }

      echo '</tr>' . "\n";
    }
    echo '</table>' . "\n"; 
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The Reader for xls files is the `Excel5` Reader.

But you really should simply use the IOFactory's load() method, and let PHPExcel identify the filetype for itself and select the correct reader, because a lot of files (particularly those downloaded from the internet) that have an `.xls` extension aren't really BIFF format files.... PHPExcel can identify and load these correctly when using the `load()` method, because it can pick the correct Reader for itself.

But when you specify a Reader such as `Excel2007` or `Excel5` yourself, you're telling PHPExcel which Reader it must use, even though it may not be the correct Reader for the actual file.

[Document link](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/ReadingSpreadsheetFiles/03-Loading-a-Spreadsheet.md), which lists all of the different Readers by name